# Which versions modified a particular function

Tags: bash, diff, clearcase

I have a VOB file which has over 100 commits (or check-ins).

Of all those commits, is there way to find out which versions (commits) have modified a particular function that I'm interested in?

The versions of the file can be accessed as `/path/to/file@@main/<version_number>`

Comment: I strongly object to closing this question as "unclear what you're asking". For anyone with clearcase experience, this question is clear enough (as evident by already 3 answers on a tag so narrow that it currently is on [page 54](http://stackoverflow.com/tags?page=54&tab=popular) of tags sorted by popularity).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach would be to make use of the virtual file system interface and just brute force extract information. Assuming that you have a script that extracts only the function you are interested in from the whole file named `extract_function.sh` (could be as simple as `sed -n '/^void your_function_name/,/^}/p'` for instance), and assuming that there are no labels shorter than 4 characters, then you can run the following commands

```
$ cd /path/to/file@@main
$ for i in ? ?? ???; do /some/where/extract_function.sh $i > /some/where/your_function.$i; done
$ cd /some/where
$ md5sum your_function.* | uniq --check-chars=32 \
| awk '{print $2}'
```

This gives you a baseline of which versions that have modified your function of interest. Then you are able to compare them by running `diff -u your_function.1 your_function.15` for instance.

The VFS interface was one thing I really, really loved about clearcase when using it; is fantastic to have all of the version control information accessible right on the command line. If you for instance wanted to correlate the checkin time of each version found above this is easily available using `ls`.

```
$ cd /some/where
$ md5sum your_function.* | uniq --check-chars=32 \
| awk '{print $2}' | cut -d. -f2 > version-numbers
$ cd /path/to/file@@main
$ xargs ls -l < /some/where/version-numbers
```

which then makes it easy to ignore versions older than x years for instance.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have access to the [extended pathnames](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?ratlid=cctocbody&rs=984&uid=swg21220890) of the versioned file, you can use a [`cleartool diff -pred`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_diff.htm?cp=SSSH27_7.1.1%2F9-0-0-1-10) on each of those versions, starting with the most recent one.

Each diff which includes lines from your function can be considered.

The most recent version can be found with [`cleartool annotate`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_annotate.htm?lang=en) though.

Comment: Thanks!! But I have lot of versions and comparing each version with previous one manually would be tedious.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with cleartool annotate, perhaps using the Visual Annotate third party tool (which drills down a little more than the standard one does).

Annotate will tell you where THIS version got the change from. You may have to annotate the stated source versions as well to get the full history.

This requires that the element type support annotate, which limits you to text file types.